# Jboss and transaction

Tags: hibernate, jboss, transactions, jta

I have an entity with two string fields: ID and NAME, NAME has nullable = false.

With jboss and hibernate i'm trying to insert three records, one of which is wrong because the field name = null. I set the transaction level to REQUIRES_NEW so i expect TWO records into the database and only one in the rollback, but instead all records are rollbacked.

Where is my error?

persistence file:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/myDS</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>           
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

entity file:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "myentity")
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {

    private String id;
    private String name;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public MyEntity() {
    }

    public MyEntity(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;

    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

EJB file:

```
@Stateless
    public class MyEJB {

        protected EntityManager em;

        @PersistenceContext(unitName = "persistenceUnit")
        public void setEm(EntityManager em) {
            this.em = em;
        }

        @Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)
        private void insert(String id, String name) {
            em.merge(new MyEntity(id, name));
        }

        public void insertTwoRecords() {
            insert("id1", "name1");
            insert("id2", null);// error field in entity is nullable = false
            insert("id3", "name3");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Transactions are proxy-based. When component `MyEJB` is injected into component `Caller`, what is actually injected is a proxy that delegates to MyEJB. Before calling MyEJB, this proxy checks the transactional annotations and starts a transaction if necessary:

```
Caller ---> proxy ----> MyEJB
```

In this case, MyEJB directly calls another, private method of itself. Not only private methods are not part of the public interface of the component, but the method call is not from one component to another, so there is no way for the proxy to intercept the call and start a new transaction.

Comment: An example of what? Just put the insert() method in another stateless bean, injected in MyEJB, and it will work as expected.